# Why a session variable lost in staging server, but works fine in localhost?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, session, iis-7

All my Search criteria should be persisted when I do searching, paging, sorting. It works fine in my localhost. But after the page is published to my staging server, every time `ChangeSort` is called, the session variable `SearchOptions` is reset to `null`.

Is there anything special in IIS that messed up my session variable?

Pasted below is the code:

```
public SearchInputModel SearchOptions
{
        get { return SessionValues.Search; }
        set { SessionValues.Search = value; }
}

public RedirectToRouteResult ChangeSort(string sortCase)
{
    if (SearchOptions == null) return RedirectToAction("Index");
    switch (sortCase)
    {
        case "ConfirmationNumber":
            {
                SearchOptions.Sort = (SearchOptions.Sort == SortEnum.ConfirmationNumberAscending)
                ? SortEnum.ConfirmationNumberDescending
                : SortEnum.ConfirmationNumberAscending;
                break;
            }
        case "LicenseNumber":
            {
                SearchOptions.Sort = (SearchOptions.Sort == SortEnum.LicenseNumberAscending)
                    ? SortEnum.LicenseNumberDescending
                    : SortEnum.LicenseNumberAscending;
                break;
            }
        case "Date":
            {
                SearchOptions.Sort = (SearchOptions.Sort == SortEnum.DateAscending)
                    ? SortEnum.DateDescending
                    : SortEnum.DateAscending;
                break;
            }
        default:
            {
                SearchOptions.Sort = SortEnum.NoSorting;
                break;
            }
    }
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

---

The `SessionValues` class is that I use to read/write session variables.

```
public class SessionValues
    {
        public static string Search
        {
            get
            {
                if (HttpContext.Current.Session["Search"] == null)
                    return null;

                return (string)HttpContext.Current.Session["Search"];
            }
            set
            {
                HttpContext.Current.Session["Search"] = value;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

In **Global.asax.cs**, I have some code to check if there is `Session_Start()` event.

```
    protected void Session_Start()
    {
        //some code to write to log file.
    }
```

Nothing is recorded from there, confirming there is no session reset.

---

**Session State** in the IIS:

[image: Session state]

Change **Session State Mode** in IIS from **SQL Server** into **In process** will fix it. But it is not a preferred solution for a load-balance server.

Comment: Where is SessionValues from? can you post the whole class?

Comment: Just updated the post to include my `SessionValues` class. Thanks for the notice.

Comment: Is your session configuration same in localhost and in staging config? I mean session state mode

Comment: @tomassino, is it in web.config or somewhere in IIS?

Comment: It should be in web.config

Comment: Sorry but which node should we look into?

Comment: does it work with in process session?

Comment: @EricKelly Yes, I can see the session variable has been set in the paging, search actions. It just cannot persist.

Comment: For better view in your question please set public class SessionValues.... in code format.

Comment: Code errors?  is it deploying/building properly?  SearchInputModel is assumed stored in session but you're using string in the supplied code which won't even compile.

Comment: Set session state on localhost to SQL server, so you will be able to catch raised exception. It might be something with serialization

Answer (score 0):

MSDN Reference: [Session-State Modes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178586.aspx)

For load balanced servers, we have to use SQL Server Session state mode, instead of **In-Process Mode**.

In this article under the section **SQL Server Mode**, there is a very important note:

> Objects stored in session state must be serializable if the mode is SQL Server. For information on serializable objects, see the SerializableAttribute class.

That is where the problem is.

Without the `[Serializable]` attribute on top of the search view model, the view model is not saved correctly. That session varialble is lost between request.

So the fix is:

```
[Serializable]
public class SearchInputModel
{
    ...
}
```